# Python Selenium WinError 193

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

I get this **error**:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application,
```

I just started learning Python and wanted to use Selenium. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix the error?

Comment: from where did you download the `chromedriver.exe` ?

Comment: maybe try with backslashes in the path there...

Comment: @cruisepandey from the https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @pcalkins i have tried that, it didnt work, thanks for commenting : )

Comment: @NeedforAnwserslol : Can you put that chromedriver.exe into a different location, may be in D driver and try again and see if that helps.

Comment: you may want to check the .exe... could be a bad corrupt download.  Double-click it to see if a console window comes up and/or check the digital signature which will verify the file's hash.

Answer (score 0):

> OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

This means that the file is not a valid executable.

Here's how to solve it:

1. [Redownload ChromeDriver.exe](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
2. Place it in `C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe`
3. Change Line 2 in your code to `PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"`